# Vertical-align absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I'm fiddling with Jquery Cycle slideshow and trying to add a couple of buttons. I can't seem to align them veritcally without `top: #px;` tomfoolery; I'd love to just align it to middle of the div vertically.

**CSS**

```
#slidecontainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}
.slidecontrols {
    top: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
.slidecontrols a {
    background-color: white;
}
.slidecontrols a.next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.bannered {
    height: 200px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slidecontainer">
    <div class="slideshow" id="slideoptions">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ufZ0cxL.jpg" class="bannered" alt="" /></a>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RZTrFy4.jpg" class="bannered" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontrols">
        <a href="#" class="next">right</a>
        <a href="#" class="prev">left</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBLcb/). Adding `vertical-align: middle;` to `.slidecontrols` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: add top: 50%;  to slidecontrols. When you have position: absolute, vertical-align will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the height of the controls will be `20px`, you could use a `top` value of `50%` and then a negative `margin-top` value of half the element's height. In this case, `-10px`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/GcBb9/)

```
.slidecontrols {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, if you need a solution for dynamic heights:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dM6Tk/)

```
.slidecontrols {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
}
.slidecontrols a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option if you don't want to guess or set any pixels:

```
.slidecontrols {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make top : 50% to slidecontrols which will align the links exactly at the center.

```
.slidecontrols {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Another posibility if you consider the buttons has 20px height,

```
top: calc(50% - 10px); // 10px is half of buttons height
```

This will align it exactly at the center

When you have `position: absolute`, the vertical align will not work.